# ng-show not hiding SPAN element in AngularJS 1.2

Tags: angularjs

I am learning AngularJS from the book AngularJS up and running. This book uses AngularJS version 1.2. One of the sample codes in the books shows how ng-show directive works. The explanation of usage of ng-show directive in this example is given as follows:

> ng-show inspect a variable and, depending on the truthiness of its
>   value, show or hide elements in the UI, respectively. In this case, we
>   say show the assignee span if note.assignee is true. AngularJS treats
>   true, nonempty strings, nonzero numbers, and nonnull JS objects as
>   truthy. **So in this case, we get to see the assignee span if the note
>   has an assignee**.

I am pasting the code below. (My query is given after the code.)

**HTML:**

```
<!-- File: chapter2/more-directives.html -->
<html ng-app="notesApp">
<head>
<title>Notes App</title>
<style>
.done {
background-color: green;
}
.pending {
background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
<div ng-repeat="note in ctrl.notes"
ng-class="ctrl.getNoteClass(note.done)">
<span class="label"> {{note.label}}</span>
<span class="assignee"
ng-show="note.assignee"
ng-bind="note.assignee">
</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Script**

```
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module('notesApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', [
function() {
var self = this;
self.notes = [
{label: 'First Note', done: false, assignee: 'Shyam'},
{label: 'Second Note', done: false},
{label: 'Done Note', done: true},
{label: 'Last Note', done: false, assignee: 'Brad'}
];
self.getNoteClass = function(status) {
return {
done: status,
pending: !status
};
};
}]);
</script>
```

In the above code, an array is declared and there are two elements (first and and the last) which have some value in the 'assignee'. When I execute this code, I get to see all the elements of the array. The ng-show directive is not hiding the 'span' with a null value in the 'assignee'. Is the code wrong or my understanding of ng-show is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this

```
<div ng-show="note.assignee">
  <span class="label"> {{note.label}}</span>
  <span class="assignee"  ng-bind="note.assignee"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay. I understand it now.  Basically the example code is only dealing with assignee span, and I was expecting that the 'label' span should also be hidden. having ng-show on Div tag is the solution for me.